# How to setup production environment for Vue and deploy app into environment

Tags: node.js, express, deployment, vuejs2

I have developed a Vue app and trying to build a dev/QA/PROD environment for the same. I knew that when i use 'npm run build', it will create dist folder with set of files/folders under it. Here i just want to know following things

1. What would be the minimal Server/Environment to execute dist files.?Is node setup enough to execute and how?
2. How to deploy dist folder to specific environment?Will it be through Git?

Answer (score 0):

Any web technology that can serve static files would do the trick.
The index.html file contained in the dist folder has links to all the javascript, css, images necessary for your app to function correctly.

So your web server has to serve index.html, and the other files have to be located in a folder accessible from any client online.

With node you can do as explained here:
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

You can also use your github account and github pages:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2MsN8gpT6jY

Comment: Okay but how we push dist folder files to specific environment or machines?